# CSS grid with certain elements in the middle (off-grid)

Tags: css, css-grid

I need to create a page using CSS grid in this format:

[image: grid]

All items have equal dimensions (400*250), are normally four in a row, but sometimes, some of them, the red in the picture, must be placed in the middle (customer's request!) as their content is more important than others.

Therefore, these 'red' containers, centered horizontally should mathematically break the 4x grid and I don't know how to do that.

On a mobile device, all of them regardless are to be on one column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be fine with a combination of Grid and flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this is what you want.

```css
.box-container{
        display: grid;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    }
    .box{
        width:150px;
        height:100px;
        border:5px solid #000;
        margin:10px 15px;
    }
    .box-imp{
        background-color:red;
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 5;
        justify-self:center;
    }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
        .box-container{
            grid-template-columns: auto;
        }
        .box-imp{
            grid-column-start: 1;
            grid-column-end: 2;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box box-imp"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box box-imp"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box box-imp"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @shotgun02 ! Exactly what I need :D. One more thing, pls: how do I make all the boxes to arrange on one column and to fill the available page's width on mobile devices ?

Comment: Hi, @HuqeDato . updated the answer for mobile devices also.